# My code for checking increasing or decreasing only in even positions is not passing for negative inputs

Tags: java

My code is not passing test cases, performance test cases and for negative inputs

```
 static String classRepresentative(int[] num,int n){
        for(int index = 0; index < num.length; index++){
            if(index % 2 == 0 && num[index] < num[index + 2]){
                return "increasing";
            }else if(index % 2 == 0 && num[index] > num[index +2]){
                return "decreasing";
            }
        }
        return "none";
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to access index out of range. Example when index = num.length-1 then index + 2 = num.length+1 which is out of bounds. So your test case will fail.

Comment: Looks like it will fail on out of bounds, since the for loop doesn't terminate early to allow for the `+2`

Comment: Also you're returning immediately rather than going through the whole array.

Comment: I don't think you're actually doing anything wrong specifically with performance or negative numbers, the other bugs just make you fail on a bunch of cases in general.

Answer (score 0):

num[index + 2] will lead to IndexOutOfBoundsException when the index is at the last position.
Change **index < num.length** to **index < num.length-2**.